# loading div with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem when loading in content with

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        $('#boundary').load('options.html #pagecontent').page();


    });
```

The problem is the #pagecontent div residing in options.html loads in but not in intended jquery mobile elements.

the  in options.html with id=page content renders fine if you preview that page. its only when i load try and load it into another page div with id="boundary" that all the jquery mobile rendering fails, and the elements instead just load in as native html elements.

in the options.html: a standard div holding some ui elements.

```
<div id="pagecontent">
     // Jquery mobile button 
      <a href="results.php" data-transition="fade" id="result" data-role="button" data-theme="e" rel="external">View results</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes (you should show some code to get a more elaborate answer)

Comment: the original question has been edited @naugtur.

Comment: is the space between options.html and #pagecontent correct? shouldn't it be options.html#pagecontent

Comment: yeah @phil the gap is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but why are you writing code to load a page div from a html file if jQuery Mobile does it by default when user clicks on a link to a page?

I recommend not writing your own AJAX support if it's not for loading data that you need to analyze and alter before adding to the page.

Comment: Ive thought about what you said which is a very valid point. The idea was to load in portions of a page which would change i.e  without necessarily sending any data but I thought this method would help optimise transitions between different parts of the app. If that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way. And you should do the pagination the old way as well, eg. `some.php?page=3` or [when using nice links] `some/3` NOT with any non-URL based ways like storing it in sessions (that example may not be the best, because it's generally bad to paginate like that ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the .page()

```
$('#boundary').load('options.html#pagecontent').page();
```

Maybe attached to the click function

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#boundary').load('options.html#pagecontent');
}).page();
```

Comment: it didnt work phil. I have re-edited the question to include more.

Comment: can you also tell me what page() does?

Comment: .page() reloads/refreshes the jQM controls to my understanding

Comment: FYI what you said is a good way of thinking about it, but in fact it is a central widget that goes through the html while the page init and triggers other widgets and adds classes for standard elements. It's good to be aware of that. It helps you understand why it sometimes doesn't work with certain bits of html when manually called upon them while the same bits are just fine when not added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution for forcing the jquery mobile rendering of loaded divs. I know that this answer came very late for you, but maybe it will help others with similar questions:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#boundary').load('options.html #pagecontent');
    $('#boundary').trigger("pagecreate").trigger("refresh");
});
```

This works for me using jquery mobile 1.1.0 (I didn't test with older versions)